# Why does uploading a 16GB file to Ubuntu One from browser on a Mac fail?

Tags: ubuntu-one, macosx

I'm uploading a 16-gb file from a Mac machine so I can access it later from my selectively synced Ubuntu one. I created a (not synced) folder from the browser and started the upload there; I see a moving stripe "Loading... please wait" popup. When I log in from another tab or computer I don't see any partial file or increase in total usage.

I first tried this from Firefox for 24 hours and then quit and tried Safari but both appear to hang with the pop-up. Is my file even uploading?

I definitely have enough available storage.

Is there any way to see the status of the upload?

Answer (score 0):

you can instal network monitor and see if it is doing something

Comment: You may want to edit this answer to explain how to do this.

Comment: An upload test puts my u/l speed at 0.42Mbps. I tested small files and they all uploaded fine with comparable upticks in the Surplusmeter output. I then watched Surplusmeter with the now day-old large upload and there was no increase in u/l logged so I restarted it. Now it appears to be loading at the same rate as the smaller files.

My follow-up question: might my network be periodically interrupted and does Ubuntu One recover interrupted files? It would be immensely helpful to have some status indicator instead of the orange bar.

Comment: Basically, all network connections get eventually interrupted, either on your side or on the server's side. Such a huge upload may or may not work, but it's a matter of chance.